# how to disable wwan0 and prevent it from starting up again?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ifconfig, linux-device-driver, wwan

I'm using a Raspberry Pi with the SIM7600E 4G hat to set up a point-to-point protocol connection, using `pppd`. This all sets up correctly all works, however when I use it to browse the internet, the modules wwan interface device (`wwan0`) comes in and interrupts the connection.

I run `ifconfig wwan0 down` which stops the interface, however it just starts back up again automatically when I start browsing and the issue continues.

I've tried blacklisting the kernal drivers that interact with the device via `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` – Disabling the option module stopped `wwan0` from appearing, however it also disabled interaction with the usb device completely, so the `/dev/ttyUSBx` ports no longer appeared. I still want to be able to send AT commands to `/dev/ttyUSB3` the while the PPP connection is on at `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

So my task is simple - I just need to override the starting of the `wwan0` interface, but from all the things I've tried from my googling nothing has worked. Any ideas?

Comment: this was cross-posted ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599242/how-to-disable-wwan0-and-prevent-it-from-starting-up-again )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `/etc/network/interfaces` you can specify that NetworkManager
shouldn't control the `wwan0` interface.

To do so, add this line:

```
iface wwan0 inet manual
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work for me @harrymc 

the `/etc/network/interfaces` file originally contained one line, `source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d`, so I even tried removing that line too, and rebooting, but all to no avail. Whenever I go into chromium, as soon as I send any GET request, the interface starts up again straight away. Interestingly, it doesn't seem to happen when I `ping` from the terminal.

Is there anything else that could be starting up `wwan0`?

Comment: We're both out of date. You are probably using networkd instead of NetworkManager. NetPlan is to be used for setting this. See for example [this article](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/).

Comment: the `/etc/netplan` directory doesn't exist on my machine, is it supposed to? should I install it? I'm running Raspian 10

Comment: Raspian has its own. See [this article](https://stevessmarthomeguide.com/configuring-networking-raspberry-pi/). Perhaps your `interfaces` is replaced by `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Too many distributions.

Comment: ha, got it, by adding the line `denyinterfaces wwan0` to `/etc/dhcpcd`. Is that what you meant to do? Or was I supposed to set up a static IP address like the article? Excuse my ignorance. I'm pretty new to network stuff @harrymc

Comment: You did the right thing. It took some time to find where Raspian has squirreled this setting.